# monacaのiPhoneデバッガーで時刻が扱えない

Tags: javascript

こんばんわ、monacaのiPhone用デバッガーで,時刻が扱えません。
現在

```
<input type="date">と<input type="time">
```

の値を取得して計算させようとしています。
取得した値をdateに入れて計算させればいいと思うのですが時刻の部分(timeの部分、00:00)
がnew Dateで扱えません。
pcでのプレビューでは

var test = new Date("2015-07-04 12:00");
var test2 = new Date("2015-07-04 11:00");
var kekka = test - test2

これでも動作はしますがiPhoneのデバッガーだとNaNになります。

var time = new Date("11:00");
console.log(time)
これでもNaNになってしまいます

どうすればいいでしょうか、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

すみません、自己解決しました、お恥ずかしいことに、new Date()を使わずに日時を記入してました。現在はデバッガーで表示されました
疲れてるのかもしれません。。失礼しました。